# How to scrape static page with multiple variants using python?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a shopee product display page. Currently I see that there are variants in the single product display page. I am unsure on how to get all variant items and their prices respectively. Please do help.

Here's an example of single page with variants
'https://shopee.co.id/ACMIC-Braided-Line-Kabel-Data-Fast-Charging-for-iPhone-1-M-2-M-3-M-i.27769962.18163430950?sp_atk=5c463b34-ab0b-40da-af85-05206b95f616&xptdk=5c463b34-ab0b-40da-af85-05206b95f616'

Currently my code is like so:

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium-wire
# set options to be headless, ..
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability(
                        "goog:loggingPrefs", {"performance": "ALL", "browser": "ALL"}
                    )
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)


shopee=['https://shopee.co.id/ACMIC-Braided-Line-Kabel-Data-Fast-Charging-for-iPhone-1-M-2-M-3-M-i.27769962.18163430950?sp_atk=5c463b34-ab0b-40da-af85-05206b95f616&xptdk=5c463b34-ab0b-40da-af85-05206b95f616']
shopeedf=pd.DataFrame()
for urls in shopee:
  try:
    driver.get(urls)
    sleep(randint(3,5))
 

    product_name=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".YPqix5").text
    try:
      normal_price=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Kg2R-S").text
    except:
      normal_price=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".X0xUb5").text
    normal_price=normal_price.replace('Rp',"").replace(".","")
    try:
      discount=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".+1IO+x").text
    except:
      discount="0"  
    compid=urls.split(".")[4].split("?")[0]
    dat={
      'product_name':product_name,
      'normal_price':normal_price,
      'discount':discount,
      'competitor_id':compid,
      'url':urls,
      'date_key':today,
      'web':'shopee'
      }
    dat=pd.DataFrame([dat])
    shopeedf=shopeedf.append(dat)
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"{urls} error")
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the variants, we could use a sub-string class name match to find the button elements, since they have different class name depending on which one is being displayed as per HTML code below:

```
<button class="product-variation product-variation--selected" aria-label="1 Meter iPhone" aria-disabled="false">1 Meter iPhone<div>...</div></button>
<button class="product-variation" aria-label="2 Meter iPhone" aria-disabled="false">2 Meter iPhone</button>
```

For a sub-string match as explained [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors), we could use ^= operator against the button class name like this: `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class^='product-variation']")`. Then, once we have all button elements, click each and get the name, price as well as discount with your code. Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

def launch_url_get_variants(url):
    ch_service = Service("driver/chromedriver")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument("--disable-Advertisement")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ch_service,options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    # wait until button is present
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='product-variation']"))
    )
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class^='product-variation']")
    for button in buttons:
        button.click()
        product_name=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".YPqix5").text
        try:
          normal_price=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Kg2R-S").text
        except:
          normal_price=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".X0xUb5").text
        normal_price=normal_price.replace('Rp',"").replace(".","")
        try:
          discount=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".+1IO+x").text
        except:
          discount="0"
        print(product_name,normal_price,discount)
```

Here is an output from a run:

```
>>> launch_url_click_get_elems('https://shopee.co.id/ACMIC-Braided-Line-Kabel-Data-Fast-Charging-for-iPhone-...')
ACMIC Braided Line Kabel Data Fast Charging for iPhone 1 M / 2 M / 3 M 99000 0
ACMIC Braided Line Kabel Data Fast Charging for iPhone 1 M / 2 M / 3 M 99000 0
ACMIC Braided Line Kabel Data Fast Charging for iPhone 1 M / 2 M / 3 M 199000 0
ACMIC Braided Line Kabel Data Fast Charging for iPhone 1 M / 2 M / 3 M 298000 0
ACMIC Braided Line Kabel Data Fast Charging for iPhone 1 M / 2 M / 3 M 298000 0
ACMIC Braided Line Kabel Data Fast Charging for iPhone 1 M / 2 M / 3 M 498000 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple variants you need to use `find_elements` method which can locate all the elements of the page. You can use CSS selector to find all the elements.

```
for urls in shopee:
    driver.get(urls)
    sleep(randint(3,5))
    variant_items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Kg2R-S")
```

Comment: this returns back an empty string. what would be ideal is to get the product variant name and the corresponding price.

Comment: did both the variant returned empty?

Comment: the variant return the price range (min - max) only as expected when seen with element inspector.